# Obfuscated DLL and Azure package deploy

Tags: azure, obfuscation

I'm using FxProtect .NET assembly obfuscator and I want to deploy the obfuscated .DLL that is in the package to Azure. How do I put back the DLL that I obfuscated back into the package? Do I unzip the .CSPKG that gets deployed to Azure and copy and paste the obfuscated DLL into the extracted .CSPKG folder and then zip it again to deploy?

Comment: that won't work b/c the package is encrypted to prevent tampering (which is essentially what you're doing).  I'd have to ask whether obfuscating is necessary since the code will be hosted/protected on Azure anyway - who's going to see it?  Still, take a look at the cspack command in the SDK for manually building a .cspkg.

Comment: The package can be encrypted, but I don't believe it is by default.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure I understand the purpose of obfuscating a DLL for deployment to the cloud?

Comment: It could be important in case anyone hacks into the servers and gets a hold of the .DLLs which may contain sensitive information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If packaging from Visual Studio or MSBUILD, I'd like to suggest that you run a post-build event that obfuscates the generated .DLL's

Comment: After some googling: http://lonerobot.net/?p=775  -- I don't know your particular command line for actual obfuscating, this you'll have to research that yourself

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation where I have a set of Azure packages that include references to assemblies which need to be obfuscated (they are part of a public SDK).  I use Dotfuscator as the obfuscation tool, but the process will likely work for other vendors as well. Here is how I solved this issue:

In my case, the Azure package(s) contain a reference to a WebRole project. That WebRole project then contains project references to several other library projects that need to be obfuscated.

The build process takes three passes:

1. Build the solution, which contains all of the libraries and web projects.  I have used the Visual Studio Configuration Manager to disable building of the Azure package projects, though that is not required.
2. Run the obfuscation tool to obfuscate the assemblies that require it.
3. Build and package just the Azure packages (via the `Publish` target) and **instruct MSBuild *not* to also build any referenced projects**.

That last part is key.  If you don't tell MSBuild to *not* build referenced projects, it will rebuild them all, undoing the obfuscation. You do this by including the property `BuildProjectReferences=false` when building the packages.

To build the Azure packages from an MSBuild script, I use the following:

```xml
<!-- This should be run after Obfuscation to ensure the SDK assemblies included in the packages are obfuscated -->
<MSBuild Projects="..\Path\My.CloudService.ccproj" Targets="Publish" Properties="BuildProjectReferences=false;PublishDir=..\artifacts\MyCloudService"  />
```

Comment: I know I'm pretty late answering this question, but I figure it could be useful for others looking for a solution in the future.